# Advice inherited method from generic abstract class in concrete non-generic class

Tags: java, spring, aop, spring-aop

For example I have the following interface

```
public interface Converter<I, O> {
    public O convert(I input);
}
```

Abstract class that implements this interface

```
public abstract class AbstractIntegerConverter<T> implements Converter<T, Integer> {

    public Integer convert(T input) {
        // convert anything to int
    }

    public abstract Integer defaultValue();
}
```

And concrete implementation

```
@Component
public class StringToIntegerConverter extends AbstractIntegerConverter<String> {

    @Override
    public Integer defaultValue() {
        // implementation
    }
}
```

I want to advice all methods that converts a `String` to anything. I created the following aspect

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class ConverterAspect {

    @Around("execution(* *..*.Converter+.convert(String))")
    public Object adviceStringConverter(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        // logic
    }
}
```

This does not work. Spring does not create a proxy for `StringToIntegerConverter` class.
However if I override `convert(String input)` method from abstract class it starts working and Spring successfully creates proxy for `StringToIntegerConverter` and executes all the needed logic.

```
@Component
public class StringToIntegerConverter extends AbstractIntegerConverter<String> {

    @Override
    public Integer convert(String input) {
        return super.convert(input);
    }

    @Override
    public Integer defaultValue() {
        // implementation
    }
}
```

Why does this happen? Is there any way to define the pointcut so I would not need to override the `convert(String input)` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `AbstractIntegerConverter` the method signature is not `public Integer convert(String input)` but `public Integer convert(T input)`, thus your pointcut `* *..*.Converter+.convert(String)` does not match. Go with `Object` or `*` instead and verify the runtime type via `args()` instead of using the compile-time signature:

```java
@Around("execution(* *..Converter+.convert(*)) && args(input)")
public Object adviceStringConverter(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, String input) throws Throwable {
    System.out.println(joinPoint);
    return joinPoint.proceed();
}
```

With my added log line you will then see on the console something like:

```
execution(Integer de.scrum_master.app.AbstractIntegerConverter.convert(Object))
```

See? `convert(Object)`, not `convert(String)`, thus the mismatch.

P.S.: This was an interesting question, not as boring as most AspectJ or Spring AOP ones. So thanks for that. `:-)`

---

**Update:**

As for your follow-up question, here is what `javap -s` prints (aspect deactivated):

```
javap -s AbstractIntegerConverter.class

Compiled from "AbstractIntegerConverter.java"
public abstract class de.scrum_master.app.AbstractIntegerConverter<T> implements de.scrum_master.app.Converter<T, java.lang.Integer> {
  public de.scrum_master.app.AbstractIntegerConverter();
    descriptor: ()V

  public java.lang.Integer convert(T);
    descriptor: (Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Integer;

  public abstract java.lang.Integer defaultValue();
    descriptor: ()Ljava/lang/Integer;

  public java.lang.Object convert(java.lang.Object);
    descriptor: (Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
}
```

See? The signature is `convert(Object)` as my aspect's log output also shows.

```
javap -s StringToIntegerConverter.class

Compiled from "StringToIntegerConverter.java"
public class de.scrum_master.app.StringToIntegerConverter extends de.scrum_master.app.AbstractIntegerConverter<java.lang.String> {
  public de.scrum_master.app.StringToIntegerConverter();
    descriptor: ()V

  public java.lang.Integer defaultValue();
    descriptor: ()Ljava/lang/Integer;
}
```

And no `convert(String)` or `convert(whatever)` method in the concrete converter class.

Do you believe me now?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is a solution that I'm currently use but I'm not quite happy with it. If `StringToIntegerConverter` extends `AbstractIntegerConverter<String>` then it does have `Integer convert(String input)` method inherited from `AbstractIntegerConverter<String>`. Doesn't it? Why then the aspect does not see it? I guess it has something to do with type erasure but `StringToIntegerConverter` is a concrete non generic class so this behaviour looks really strange for me.

Comment: No, it does not. I don't know how you think inheritance works, but not by copying byte code into inherited classes. The method is still defined in the abstract class and thus generic, i.e. effectively the method signature contains `Object`, not `String`, as you can easily check with `javap -c`. So my solution is not some dirty workaround with which you should be unhappy, it is the correct solution because you coded your classes that way. My aspect's log output also proves it: `AbstractIntegerConverter.convert(Object)`.

Comment: I added `javap -s` output (not so verbose) to my answer for your convenience and hope you can accept it now.

Comment: I don't know how exactly inheritance works on low level but I know for sure that when we extend a generic class the type parameters which we specify is somehow saved. We then can get generic type parameters from concrete inheritors in runtime as explained in [Super Type Tokens](http://gafter.blogspot.com/2006/12/super-type-tokens.html). So I thought there is a way to tell AspectJ to utilize this information as well.

Comment: Last time I checked I showed you a way to do that, isn't that what my code does? I am sorry you disapprove of the realities of JVM class file structure and how it is used by AspectJ, but I am afraid there is nothing I can do in order to change that for you.

Comment: For your reference, this is a description of how to use [generics in AspectJ](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/adk15notebook/generics-inAspectJ5.html). AspectJ inspects bytecode, and the bytecode for the method you want to match has a generic parameter type, thus type erasure applies. This also explains why it works if you directly define the method in the concrete subclass because there you give it a specific parameter type.